# Rain CSS effect not working in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, google-chrome-extension

I made an HTML page that rains using CSS for the background color and javascript for the. Now I am trying to make a chrome extension that makes it rain in the background of the google search page. However, only the background color (CSS file) is applied and I don't see the rain. what can I do so it also shows the rain animation?

JSON:

```json
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Weather Back",
  "description": "change the background of google search bar",
  "version": "1.1",
  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["https://www.google.com/"],
    "css":["style.css"],
    "js": ["main.js"]
  }]
}
```

```js
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.style.position = "fixed";
canvas.id = "rainy-background";
document.body.appendChild(canvas);

//Global
var c, ctx, vRain;

//Rain
class Rain {
  //coordinate + length + velocity
  constructor(x, y, l, v) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.vy = v;
    this.l = l;
  }

  show() {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = "white";
    ctx.moveTo(this.x, this.y); //initial fall
    ctx.lineTo(this.x, this.y + this.l); //final fall;
    ctx.stroke();
  }

  fall() {
    this.y += this.vy;

    if (this.y > c.height) {
      this.x = Math.floor(Math.random() * c.width) + 5;
      this.y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) - 100;
      this.l = Math.floor(Math.random() * 30) + 1;
      this.vy = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12) + 4;
    }

  }
}

//Loop
function loop() {

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);

  for (var i = 0; i < vRain.length; i++) {
    vRain[i].show();
    vRain[i].fall();
  }
}

function setup() {
  c = document.getElementById("canvas");
  ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  vRain = [];
  //to make rain harder, set i higher
  for (var i = 0; i < 250; i++) {
    vRain[i] = new Rain(
      Math.floor(Math.random() * c.width) + 5,
      Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) - 100,
      Math.floor(Math.random() * 30) + 1,
      Math.floor(Math.random() * 12) + 4,
    );
  }

  setInterval(loop, 10);
}

window.onload = setup();

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', setup)
```

```css
html body {
  background: linear-gradient(#361e56, rgb(150, 145, 153));
}

canvas {
  width: "2000";
  height: "1000";
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Rain animation</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <center>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="2000" height="1000"></canvas>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </center>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Debug using DevTools.

Comment: 1) Replace the last two lines (window.onload and addEventListener) with `setup()`. 2) Maybe add `*` after `https://www.google.com/` to run on result pages too.